# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't see kindle fire as as mtp device

Tags: 14.04, usb, mtp, kindle

When I connect my kindle fire to my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop with a micro usb cable, nothing happens. When I check my syslog I get this.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog 
Sep  5 16:26:22 ubuntu kernel: [539971.504102] usb 1-8.4: USB disconnect, device number 18
Sep  5 16:26:27 ubuntu kernel: [539975.552287] usb 1-8.4: new high-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
Sep  5 16:26:27 ubuntu kernel: [539975.650655] usb 1-8.4: New USB device found, idVendor=1949, idProduct=000d
Sep  5 16:26:27 ubuntu kernel: [539975.650663] usb 1-8.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep  5 16:26:27 ubuntu kernel: [539975.650668] usb 1-8.4: Product: Android
Sep  5 16:26:27 ubuntu kernel: [539975.650672] usb 1-8.4: Manufacturer: Android
Sep  5 16:26:27 ubuntu kernel: [539975.650676] usb 1-8.4: SerialNumber: B05707063456002C
Sep  5 16:26:27 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 19: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8.4"
Sep  5 16:26:27 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 19 was not an MTP device
```

Comment: Have you installed the mtpfs and mtpfs-tools packages?  Those are necessary.